# Getting "protoc": executable file not found in $PATH when running "go generate" command

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, proto, grpc-go

We have an application written in GoLang and we are using GRPC for defining service contracts.

When we try to run "go generate" command to generate stub from proto file it gives following error:

```
main.go:4: running "protoc": exec: "protoc": executable file not found in $PATH
```

Command format in code:

```
//go:generate protoc -I . --go-grpc_out=. --go_out=.  ./proto/service.proto
```

Note:

- I have already installed **protoc-gen-go** and **protoc-gen-go-grpc**
- Tried to search for the above error but haven't been able to find a solution yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`protoc-gen-go` and `protoc-gen-go-grpc` are **plugins** for `protoc`. You need to install the `protoc` (the Protobuf compiler) itself, as explained in [Go gRPC - Prerequisites](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/go/quickstart/#prerequisites).

See [protobuf - Releases](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases) page for a download.

On a Mac can just use `brew install protobuf`.

Comment: After installing protoc using brew install protobuf I could use "go generate". Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Installing protobuf-complier woker for me.

```
yum install protobuf-compiler
```